# Calculate age in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a date of birth in excel 23-05-2015(dd/mm/yyyy) and I need to calculate age.I tried the formula =DATEDIF(C3,TODAY(),"Y") but am getting an error as #VALUE!.When I evaluate the formula it shows as =DATEDIF("23/05/2015",42866,"Y").
I guess it is because of date format (dd/mm/yyyy), is there any method where I can achieve this.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Simply write `=Today-C3` and then press `Ctrl+1` and select `Number` for the format. The answer is in days.

Or try like this:

`=DATEDIF(DATE(YEAR(A24),MONTH(A24),DAY(A24)),TODAY(),"Y")`

Comment: Should be `=Today() - C3` I think. Which will give the age in days.

Comment: @Vityata format for c3 is dd/mm/yyyy which is UK standard format for date.

Comment: @Sunil doesn't it work? Probably the string is not formatted as date.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert string to date inside `DATEDIF()`:

```
=DATEDIF(DATE(RIGHT(A1,4),MID(A1,4,2),LEFT(A1,2)),TODAY(),"y")
```

And if you love big formulas:

```
=DATE(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","@",(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","")))))),MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","@",(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","")))))-FIND("-",A1)-1),LEFT(A1,2))
```

Comment: Sure, if you like larger formulas i can make that one as well :)

Answer (score 1):

I used the following formula which returned me the correct answer in years.

=DATEDIF(DATE1, DATE2, "Y")

You can use the following link to get the required info.

https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-datedif-function

[You can check the screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17uLe.png)

Comment: Yes Sunil, I tried that date, please check the attached screenshot.

Comment: Please check screenshot which I attached, need in that format as the dates DATE1 and DATE2 keeps changing. I need to apply the formula for more than 100 records.

Comment: I tried the formula you used to work again! What do you need to achieve?

Comment: I want to calculate age and its not working. Am getting error as #Value!
I have attached new screenshot of evaluating the formula. What might be the issue

Comment: Why don't you try to take the difference and then take the int, or the round of that difference?